# Frontend UI for faster load

Tags: php, javascript, css, user-interface

I have data in MySQL Database which i want to Display on my website.

The data can be represented in table which can be sorted filtered etc.

Also need a search option.(Like autocomplete)

I had made UI on GWT which is quite fast for sorting etc.

But for starting my Webhosting is shared hosting on Hostgator(so cannot run GWT)
Which framework should i use for beautiful and fast UI .
I read about twitter bootstrap but can it handle filtering, sorting etc.

Comment: Why can't you use GWT with Hostgator? Getting the UI should be as easy as uploading the generated files. Is it because you can't do RPC?

Comment: Yes the data is dynamic and Tomcat hosting is very expensive :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a responsive framework used to develop a user interface on the client.

Any sorting or filtering would be done either by using a client side JavaScript framework like jQuery or server side using PHP, Asp.Net, etc.